# Recomputing coordinate in image rotation

Tags: python, image, rotation

Imagine having a picture (the reference in the images
are on the top left corner, in the pic I have uploaded it's near the 0,0 corner).
With different libraries it's easy to rotate the image.
Now, associated with the pic you have a specific point for which you have to recompute its coordinates in respect to the rotation you have applied to the pic.
So, let's say your image is square and you apply a rotation of 90 degrees clockwise.  Your point initially have coordinates x=4, y=1 and after the
rotation should have 3,4.

Is the following code correct to recompute the coordinates of such point (or any other point?)?
I have strong doubts about the "if" conditions. I wonder if I should apply another operation that involves the modulo.

```
import numpy as np

def rot(x,y, ang):
  xn=np.cos(ang)*x + np.sin(ang)*y
  yn=-np.sin(ang)*x + np.cos(ang)*y
  return [xn,yn]


x=4
y=1
mpx=4 # width of the image
mpy=4 # height of the image

# 3 rotations of 90 degrees
a=np.arange(2.0*np.pi, 0, -np.pi/2.0) 
print(a)
for i in a:
  xn,yn=rot(x,y,i)

  if(xn<0):
    xn+=mpx
  if(yn<0):
    yn+=mpy

  print("%f %f" %(xn,yn))
```

[image]

Comment: no you are pushing all points that fall out of the domain of the array in which is invalid, you need to create a new image of `0`s and only move pixels over whose destination fits into the new image, so if `xn` or `yn` < 0 or > imagesize they need to be ignored

Comment: There is no array, there are no pixels.  There are only numeric coordinates that need to be re-calculate in the new reference after the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

After the rotation operation, you can apply these two steps and remove the if conditions:

```
xn = mpx - xn
yn = abs(yn)
```

This should give you the correct results for the rotations.

Comment: Well... I am not sure about that.  Imagine doing a very very small rotation (just to test in our mind the effect of your code). Practically the X coordinate will remain the same (also the Y).  If I apply your code instead, the new X coordinate will be "mpx -xn", a HUGE change.